# Strange class array issue - can't show it in jsp

Tags: java, class, jsp

I'm creating an array in my class and then, I'm returning it back to a jsp.

The array code is:

```
private String[] appNames = new String[50];


    public String[] getAppNames() {
        return appNames;
    }


    public void setAppNames(String[] appNames) {
        this.appNames = appNames;
    }
```

In my jsp I'm trying to show it like this:

```
<%
String username = session.getAttribute("username").toString();
Menu val = new Menu(username);
    System.out.println(val.getAppNames());

%>
```

and what I'm getting is:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@7022c24e
```

I'm pretty sure that I'm missing something small. I guess that I can not create getters and setters for an array in the class, but I'm still a java beginner. Is it possible to get the value of the array in my jsp, or I have to call a servlet by ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the correct `array` the only problem is that you are printing the array, hence you are getting that output. If you want it to be printed in  a beautified way then you need to override the toString method in your Menu class.

As far as the usage of `array`, you have not shared any code but you can put a loop to iterate over that array and confirm that you are getting the values at the desired indices.

Answer (score 2):

You are directly printing the array object here :

```
System.out.println(val.getAppNames());
```

Since array is an object , it uses the default implementation of [toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) defined in the `Object` class to print the contents of the array object.

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> **getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())**

Hence you get such an output.

If you need to output it to the console , you can use [Arrays#toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) method:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(val.getAppNames()));
```

I think , probably , you want to display it in the page . You can use JSTL [forEach](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) .

```
<c:forEach var="element" items="yourArrayObject">
    Item : <c:out value="${element}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: +1 but this comes up so often there should be an option to close a question because "yet another question about java arrays 'not printing correctly' - use Arrays.toString()"

Answer (score 0):

Use `<c:forEach>` to [iterate over the array](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_foreach_tag.htm)